# AHK Script to send different button with each successive press

Tags: autohotkey

Okay so I wrote this script in AHK to press 2 on the first press of the mouse button and 3 on the second and so on, yet it doesnt work. Any ideas why ?

> XButton1::Send, 1;
>
> XButton2::
>
> x:=1
>
> if (x = 1){
>
> Send, 2
>     x+=1
>
> } else if (x = 2) {
>
> Send, 3
>     x+=1
>
> } else if (x = 3) {
>
> Send, 4
>     x+=1
>
> } else if (x = 4) {
>
> Send, 5
>     x = x - 3
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you press XButton2, you reset the value of x to 1....`x:=1`. So it will obviously only send 2.  You need to set the value of x outside of XButton2. This will work:

```
x := 1

XButton2::
x += 1
SendInput, %x%
return
```

Comment: I tried that before but it didn't change anything. It still didn't send any buttons at all.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the expected behavior and what you are actually experiencing? The above is a tested example that worked fine based on my understanding of your case--on first press it sends 2, second press 3, third press 4, etc.